# when using RestRequest req = RestContext.request; i cannot save the File throws save Error

Tags: apex, rest-api, managed-package

Compile Error: Variable does not exist: RestContext.request

when using

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
```

i cannot save the File throws save Error

Answer (score 1):

Most likely scenario: you've masked `RestContext` with a custom class by the same name. If so, you will need to use the full namespace:

```
System.RestRequest req = System.RestContext.request;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you got another Apex class called RestContext in your application?

For example the following code gives the error ...

> Variable does not exist: RestContext.request

Because I've created a class called RestContext and this 'shadows' the System one.

```
public class RestContext  { }

public void test () {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request; 
}
```

You can instead qualify the RestContext class by its System namespace like so...

```
public class RestContext  { }

public void test () {
    RestRequest req = System.RestContext.request; 
}
```

**NOTE:** The Apex Developer guide covers 'Shadowing' [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm), but omits the Class use case. I've submitted this question via the documentation feedback option. ;-)

Comment: thats the same i had a class with this name hidden to me worked thanks

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be more common these days, i guess the more classes get added to the system namespace. Hopefully Salesforce documentation people will read this SE question and see it needs improving. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The variable does not exist error can come when your scope gets messed due to incorrectly matched curly braces. Double check that. I'm providing an example of how you should use the RestRequest declaration. Hope this helps

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/demo')
global class Demo1 {
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, req.requestBody.toString());
        return '';
    }
}
```